# CouchDB 1.5.1 missing documents | "TimeOut", "Reason for termination == killed"

Tags: database, couchdb, documents

I'm using couchDB to save importants documents and i've been seeing a lot of crashes in my logs lately.
Moreover, all my documents are missing. My database had 3GB before the crashes, 
today my database has only 2MB. Apparently i lost 3000 documents with this issue. Somebody may help me?

Here is the log!

```

```
    [Mon, 01 Feb 2016 18:05:18 GMT] [error] [<0.11666.0>] {error_report,<0.34.0>,
                              {<0.11666.0>,crash_report,
                               [[{initial_call,
                                     {couch_replicator_httpc_pool,init,
                                         ['Argument__1']}},
                                 {pid,<0.11666.0>},
                                 {registered_name,[]},
                                 {error_info,
                                     {exit,killed,
                                         [{gen_server,terminate,6},
                                          {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}},
                                 {ancestors,
                                     [<0.11665.0>,couch_replicator_job_sup,
                                      couch_primary_services,couch_server_sup,
                                      <0.35.0>]},
                                 {messages,[{'EXIT',<0.11667.0>,normal}]},
                                 {links,[]},
                                 {dictionary,[]},
                                 {trap_exit,true},
                                 {status,running},
                                 {heap_size,233},
                                 {stack_size,24},
                                 {reductions,216}],
                                []]}}
    [Mon, 01 Feb 2016 18:05:48 GMT] [error] [<0.182.0>] httpd 500 error response:
     {"error":"timeout"}

    [Mon, 01 Feb 2016 18:05:48 GMT] [error] [<0.11703.0>] ** Generic server <0.11703.0> terminating 
    ** Last message in was {'EXIT',<0.11702.0>,killed}
    ** When Server state == {state,"https://XXXXX.XXXXX.com.br/mydatabase/",
                                   20,[],
                                   [<0.11704.0>],
                                   {[],[]}}
    ** Reason for termination == 
    ** killed

[Mon, 01 Feb 2016 18:05:48 GMT] [error] [<0.11703.0>] {error_report,<0.34.0>,
                          {<0.11703.0>,crash_report,
                           [[{initial_call,
                                 {couch_replicator_httpc_pool,init,
                                     ['Argument__1']}},
                             {pid,<0.11703.0>},
                             {registered_name,[]},
                             {error_info,
                                 {exit,killed,
                                     [{gen_server,terminate,6},
                                      {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}},
                             {ancestors,
                                 [<0.11702.0>,couch_replicator_job_sup,
                                  couch_primary_services,couch_server_sup,
                                  <0.35.0>]},
                             {messages,[{'EXIT',<0.11704.0>,normal}]},
                             {links,[]},
                             {dictionary,[]},
                             {trap_exit,true},
                             {status,running},
                             {heap_size,377},
                             {stack_size,24},
                             {reductions,236}],
                            []]}}
[Tue, 02 Feb 2016 09:49:27 GMT] [error] [<0.136.0>] httpd 500 error response:
 {"error":"error","reason":"Couldn't open document `_design/vdfpl` from source database `mydatabase`: {error,<<\"not_found\">>}"}
```